# Windows Phone 7: Login and Registering in local to remote

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have just built a screen where a user can write his own email address and password. Now, when the user clicks on the button "Login", i need Windows Phone app connects to a page in PHP that says to Windows Phone app if that user is already registered. if not, PHP page creates a new account and sends a validation email to the user.
Otherwise, if the user is already registered, PHP page returns a code that says to my Windows Phone app that the current user has already registered.
Now, Windows Phone app will upload a local file (a text file) to my website (where the user has logged in), deleting the one already present.
How to do this? Do i have to use LINQ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:
1. Standard HTTP request over SSL (HTTPS)
2. A standard POST variables for submitting login and password
3. XML response
4. Linq for easy XML decoding

Also, on the server put each of the routines in separate module, e.g. login.php and send.php (to e.g. send message).
So index.php would load the modules like index.php?module=login and you would have to pre-define modules in index.php.

I believe this is far the simplest way of doing it. If you dont use XML for submitting login its far more easier to secure it on the web server level before malformed login hits PHP worker. This is also because of the security, so this way you can later separate login to something else if you plan having millions of users.
Also, when loading a module, you need to make sure this module exists and not by file_exists but by pre-defined array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make web request to your PHP page for your login methods and it will return you response as per your specified Way. Then you can parse that response or show the things as per your logic.